react app not working while i run using nmp start command
npm start not working
throw error
PS D:\REACT_APPLICATION\Good> npm start 
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path D:\REACT_APPLICATION\Good\package.json
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\REACT_APPLICATION\Good\package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\harpr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-30T08_52_13_120Z-debug-0.log

npm start not working while run react app how to fix it

There is no package.json in that directory. npm can't know what to start without one.

This error message indicates that there is no package.json file in your root directory.
Make sure that you are in the correct directory where your package.json file is located.
Content of package.json file looks like this:
{
  "name": "name-of-the-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   // ...devDependencies
  }
}

